# Porque el pdf que genero esta en blanco?

Tags: laravel, pdf, laravel-7, dompdf

Estoy tratando de generar un pdf usando DOMPDF con laravel-7 pero cuando lo genero el pdf se encuentra en blanco y no muestra nada de mi vista.

Esta es la manera en la que inclui el paquete luego de hacer

```
composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf
```

App.php:

En los providers

```
Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider::class,
```

Y en los aliases

```
'PDF' => Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade::class,
```

Este es mi metodo en el controlador:

```
public function PDFProducts(){

    $products = Product::all();

    $pdf = \PDF::loadView('pdf-products', $products);
    return $pdf->stream('products.PDFProducts');
}
```

y esta es mi ruta en web.php

```
Route::get('/pdfproducts', 'Backend\ProductController@PDFProducts')->name('products.PDFProducts');
```

Luego este es mi boton que llama a la ruta y me genera el pdf:

```
<a title="PDF" id="pdf" class="btn btn-sm btn-info btn btn-success" href="{{route('products.PDFProducts')}}" ><i class="fas fa-print" ></i></a>
```

Y esta es mi vista llamada pdf-products.blade.php donde solo contengo un h1:

```
<h1>TEST</h1>
```

Y asi se ve mi pdf:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A alguien se le ocurre alguna razon por lo que mi pdf no muestra nada y se encuentra en blanco (vacío)?

Esta es la estructura que me devuelve la consola de dev tools al inspeccionar:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body cz-shortcut-listen="true">
    <div class="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Y no el h1 que tengo

Comment: en la vista del pdf solo tienes ese h1?, te recomiendo agregar toda la estructura de HTML y agregas el h1, tambien Y CREO Q ESE ES EL PROBLEMA, a la hora de pasarle a variable $products a la vista, lo debes hacer con \PDF::loadView('pdf-products', compact($products));

Comment: Ya intente todas las maneras que dijiste, pasandole estrucutra html, pasarle la variable usando compact, todas conllevan al mismo problema @HeynerMartinez

Comment: Lo que quiere decir es que no estan llegando nunca a la vista en mi caso lo uso de esta forma y no he tenido problemas, lo que hago es descargarlo en ves de mostrarlo, $pdf = $pdf=PDF::setOptions(['isRemoteEnabled'=>true])->loadView('Reportes.descargar_boletin_parcial',compact('notas)); $pdf->download()

Comment: @HeynerMartinez podrias insertarlo en modo de respuesta?

Answer (score 0):

YO ocupo este método para descargar un pdf puedes probarlo

```
$notas=notas::get();
$pdf=PDF::setOptions(['isRemoteEnabled'=>true])->loadView('Reportes.descargar_boletin_parcial',compact('notas)); 
$pdf->download();
```

Comment: No cambia el problema, sigue en blanco. Creo que estoy teniendo un problema con bootstrap. Existe alguna manera en la que bootsrap bloquee la funcion de generar un pdf?